# how to land up on the bitstream url from the href link of an html

Tags: r, rvest, bitstream, pdftools

I am using `rvest` `R` package to scrape a PDF file from [this](http://judgmenthck.kar.nic.in/judgments/handle/123456789/563560) webpage but the final link is exposed (as a bitstream url - whatever it is) after I click on the `exposed url` by name `AC1-96-21-01-2011.pdf`. The final pdf file is tucked in [here](http://judgmenthck.kar.nic.in/judgments/bitstream/123456789/563560/2/AC1-96-21-01-2011.pdf) hidden from access. This blocks all attempts of `rvest` function `read_html()` as the final pdf file opens only on clicking on the previous link (on `href`). Copy pasting the `xml node` that is not allowing me to enter into the pdf file.

```
<a href="/judgments/handle/123456789/701">Arbitration Case - AC</a>
```

The final file is on this url which is not exposed in the `href` node.
    http://judgmenthck.kar.nic.in/judgments/bitstream/123456789/563560/2/AC1-96-21-01-2011.pdf

So as a summary how do I access the pdf file link using `rvest` that is not found in the `href` attribute as explained above.

I tried to search `bitstream` but it takes my to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong node I think:

```r
library(rvest)

"http://judgmenthck.kar.nic.in/judgments/handle/123456789/563560" %>%
read_html()                                                       %>%
html_nodes(xpath = "//td/a[@target='_blank']")                    %>%
html_attr("href")                                                 %>% 
unique()                                                          %>% 
{grep("[.]pdf", ., value = T)}                                    %>%
paste0("http://judgmenthck.kar.nic.in", .)                         ->
pdf_url

print(pdf_url)
# [1] "http://judgmenthck.kar.nic.in/judgments/bitstream/123456789/563560/2/AC1-96-21-01-2011.pdf"
```

Comment: Aha, I learnt about the `target="_blank"` attribute value today. Was always filtering nodes on `href` attribute and hence missing the actual link. Thanks a lot, I will accept your answer @Allan.

Comment: could you recommend a suitable tutorial on `xpath`? I tried a few but they stop after giving elementary examples.

Comment: HI Lazarus. I think I started with the simple tutorial on w3 schools at `https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp` and built up knowledge as needed from Stack Overflow. If you type `[xpath]` into the search bar at the top of the Stack Overflow page you'll find some great questions and answers.